# Is 3.1 USB port bound by 3.0 speed in my laptop?

Tags: windows, usb, chipset

I have *MSI GE62VR Apache Pro* laptop. I was looking into my USB ports to understand whether my USB-C port is 3.1 Gen2.

**I have a few questions:**

1. As I understand correctly from the screenshots below, it seems that I have a 3.1 Controller which is bound by 3.0 version? Does this mean that the speed is limited by 5Gbps which is less then the 3.1 Gen2 speed (10Gbps)?
2. Why the 3.1 Controller is listed under the Chipset and the 3.0 Controller is by itself?
3. Why would MSI put an Intel Controller for the 3.0 and the AMD Controller for 3.1 and not the same for both of them?

This is the screenshot from Device Manager:
[image]

This information is from HWiNFO tool:
[image]
[image]

Comment: not sure but maybe another way to look into it is to test the speeds?  (not sure how you'd test it though 'cos many devices are quite slow!), though i haven't looked into it but maybe many people have ideas on how you can test the speed

Comment: One controller is probably integrated in the chipset, the other is a discrete chip connected with PCIe. As to why different vendors - probably because there's no reason not to do it and it was cheaper that way.

Comment: @gronostaj, you mean one controller is in PCH chipset (southbridge)? If yes, I thought the PCH chip is responsible for the USB ports. Therefore, I thought there is one controller with many hubs and not several controllers.